# What's the convention for reusing variable names for both JSP pages and Java Servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

Normally it's taught to use variables in order to duplicate intances of the same value so that all can be updated with one line of code change. This is basic programming.

Currently I'm writing a JSP page that interacts with a Java servlet but the names of the input forms are written in pure text such as name="formInput1" and I have to duplicate the name in pure text with res.getParamter("formInput1") inside my servlet code.

This is bad practice in general and there HAS to be a better way to go about doing it but my google searches aren't getting me anywhere productive. Does anyone know? I want to share variable names between my JSP pages and servlet java code! What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use an annotation to change the mapping if you use Spring. Also, you aren't "sharing" variables - it looks like you're submitting forms from a web browser and building dynamic pages.

Comment: Right only sharing going on is the name of the variables. Unfortunately I'm not using Spring though I'm using Google App Engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would be to have a Class for constants

```
package com.my.pakage;

public class FormConstants {
    public static final String formInput1="formInput1";

}
```

and then do the imports in jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.my.pakage.FormConstants" %>
```

to use it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="<%=FormConstants.formInput1%>">
```

and normally in your Java files:

```
import com.my.pakage.FormConstants
```

Comment: Does nto work for me.. I missing something basic I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632174/reusing-variable-names-between-jsp-and-java-spring