# Reusing variable names between jsp and java (Spring)

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, jstl

My existing jsp is

```
<c:forEach var="domainOrGroupParentDetails"
    items="${allDomainOrGroupParentDetails}" varStatus="status">
    <option
        value="${domainOrGroupParentDetails.domainOrGroupParentPojo.name}">
        ${domainOrGroupParentDetails.domainOrGroupParentPojo.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

My existing Spring Java is

```
data.put("allDomainOrGroupParentDetails",
    getDomainOrGroupParentResponse.getDomainOrGroupParentPojoWrappers());
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561515/whats-the-convention-for-reusing-variable-names-for-both-jsp-pages-and-java-ser), I tried to do the following

```
public class ModelObjectKeys {
    public static class OnLoadAddDriverConstants {

    }
    public static final String allDomainOrGroupParentDetails = "allDomainOrGroupParentDetails";
}
```

And in the jsp I did

```
<c:forEach var="domainOrGroupParentDetails"
    items="${<%=ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails%>}" varStatus="status">
    <option
        value="${domainOrGroupParentDetails.domainOrGroupParentPojo.name}">
        ${domainOrGroupParentDetails.domainOrGroupParentPojo.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

I also imported the java file in the html like this

```
<%@ page import="com.mnox.corporate.model.design.ModelObjectKeys"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
```

Still it does not work. I get

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   /WEB-INF/views/onLoadAddDriverView.jsp (line: 270, column: 10)
>   "${<%=ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails%>}" contains
>   invalid expression(s)

What am I missing ?

**EDIT**

```
Jun 19, 2017 7:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/BuseetaCorporate] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/onLoadAddDriverView.jsp at line 271

268:                                        <c:forEach var="domainOrGroupParentDetails"
269:                                            items="${ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails}" varStatus="status">
270:                                            <option
271:                                                value="${domainOrGroupParentDetails.domainOrGroupParentPojo.name}">
272:                                                ${domainOrGroupParentDetails.domainOrGroupParentPojo.name}</option>
273:                                        </c:forEach>
274:                                    </select>
Stacktrace:] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'domainOrGroupParentPojo' not found on type java.lang.String
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  `items="${<%=ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails%>}"` 
to  `items="${ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails}"`

You can't nest scripting inside EL expression

Comment: What kind of error do you get? allDomainOrGroupParentDetails has to be collection to be out in `items`

Comment: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` in the "console" of Chrome's Inspect

Comment: Notice, that it is.. `data.put("allDomainOrGroupParentDetails",
    getDomainOrGroupParentResponse.getDomainOrGroupParentPojoWrappers());`

Comment: What is the type of ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails?

Comment: ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails is a String, its in the Question clearly mentioned above ?

Comment: Can you change it to String array?

Comment: Why would I do that ? Its `not` a string array.. Note : I had added more info in the question

Comment: Because `c:forEach` requires collection.

Comment: `data.put("allDomainOrGroupParentDetails"` is a collection, again please read the question

Comment: You need to put your scoped variable of domainOrGroupParentDetails bean as an attribute, so it can be accessed through the nested property 
ex : `request.setAttribute("domainOrGroupParentDetails", domainInstance);`, otherwise it is considered as String, and String indeed does not have property of `domainOrGroupParentPojo`, which is error you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

`${<%=ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails%>}` should be like `${ModelObjectKeys.allDomainOrGroupParentDetails}`

Comment: Are you sure about the `${<` ?